# How to repair the keyboards in laptops?

Tags: windows-10

All keys on my laptop works well except z ,x,c,v,b,n,m,<,> and space. But all the keys works while using exernal keyboard. What should i do to repair the unworking keys?

Comment: Get a replacement keyboard and switch them out. There's probably something wrong with the circuits in the keyboard membrane.

Comment: Without a picture of your keyboard, it's impossible to know for sure, but it sounds like the problem involves not quite a full row of keys plus one key on a different row.  You can get this kind of pattern from spilling some liquid into your keyboard.  If so, it might be possible to clean and dry it.  But you would need to access it as described in Julie Pelletier's answer, and fixing it wouldn't be guaranteed.  Best case, you would save the cost of a replacement keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You would most likely need to order a replacement keyboard, open the laptop casing completely, disconnect the old keyboard, replace it with the new one and reassemble the laptop.

This is obviously not an easy task and laptop casings are not typically well designed to be opened, so you should expect that the operation may cause additional damage.  If you're very careful, it may be possible to do it without any incident but in my experience, there are often esthetic damages if not worse.

Comment: how much does it costs? what are the damages that i must face on my laptop.

Comment: I've taken apart hundreds of laptops when I was young and worked at a PC repair shop. I disagree with your point that opening them often has aesthetics damages. Most people are just careless and try to rip things open without caring. The tricky part is making sure all of the screws are out before trying to force something open.

Comment: @UksMikchan look up a video on disassembling your laptop. Sometimes you don't have to take apart anything. Some laptops you just remove two screws from the bottom of the laptop and use a paperclip to push into the hole which will pop out the keyboard, and give you access to the keyboard ribbon.

Comment: @DrZoo:  I agree that it is possible to do it neatly by someone that is skilled and ideally experienced, but those people don't ask a general question on how to do it.  I merely said it as a warning which is most justified in my experience.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I've seen a few people use knives or screwdrivers as pry tools...

Comment: And aslo my laptop battery doesn't increase when it is stand-by charged but increases readily when i shut it down. what should i do?

Comment: @UksMikchan That's a different question. It has nothing to do with your faulty keyboard.